# SQL query for null values

Tags: sql, oracle

There is one table TABLE_NAME:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | null | null |
| A1 | null | C1 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |

I have 3 optional input parameters, A, B, C all of them are string (varchar).I want exact response for eg. if A = A1, B= null and C = null. I should get -

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | null | null |

Instead I am getting -

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | null | null |
| A1 | null | C1 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |

I tried using below queries:
@A here is A1, @B is null and @C is null
1.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE (@A IS NULL OR A=@A) 
AND (@B IS NULL OR B=@B) 
AND (@C IS NULL OR C=@C)
```

2.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE A = NVL(:@A , A) AND B = NVL(:@B , B) AND C = NVL(:@C , C)
```

None of the above queries give me the expected result that is:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | null | null |

I am using oracle db for this. How can I query above thing?

Comment: Please explain better your question, it's not clear

Comment: What are you passing as @A, @B, @C?

Comment: Which database are you really using? SQL tag is for a **language**; did you mean MS SQL Server? Oracle SQL Developer is a GUI tool, which is most probably irrelevant here. "Oralce" (?) should've probably been "Oracle", but - if you use MS SQL Server, then you don't use Oracle and vice versa.

Comment: Maybe `WHERE ((@A IS NULL AND A IS NULL) OR A=@A)` (etc)?

Answer (score 0):

So, the root of your problem is in SQL server NULL doesn't equal NULL.  You simply need to change it to something else that won't have a chance to collide with a value that exists in the table.  Using the ISNULL function you can convert it to something else that cannot collide.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE ISNULL(A, 'X$X') = ISNULL(@A, 'X$X') AND ISNULL(C, 'X$X') = ISNULL(@C, 'X$X')
```

Comment: I am using Oracle DB.

Comment: @SakshiK then replace `ISNULL(..)` with `NVL(..)`